# How to calculate the center manifold of the system of ODEs?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've encountered a problem like this:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{y_1}=-y_1+y_2^2,\\
\dot{y_2}=y_2,\\
\dot{y_3}=y_1y_2
\end{array}\right.\notag
\end{eqnarray}
The linerized matrix has a zero,so clearly, it should have a center manifold at $(0,0,0)$.

It's easy to solve that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y_1=\left(y_1(0)-\frac{y_2^2(0)}{3}\right)e^{-t}+\frac{y_2^2(0)}{3}e^{2t},\\
y_2=y_2(0)e^{t},\\
y_3=y_2(0)\left(y_1(0)-\frac{y_2^2(0)}{3}\right)t+\frac{y_2^3(0)}{3}e^{3t}+y_3(0)-\frac{y_2^3(0)}{9}
\end{array}\right.\notag
\end{eqnarray}
But I have no idea how to get the parametric representation of the center manifold.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy in this case: $(0,0,y_3)$, which is a line of fixed points.

Comment: But how to prove that? I should know $y_3(0,0)=0$ as well as $D y_3(0,0)=0$,which drives me mad..